# How to deal with "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named" error?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea, persistence

Getting the error "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named" while trying to run Java Maven project in IntelliJ, the project runs fine in Visual studio Code with no errors or warnings

i'm not fully sure what code be causing the issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named default
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
    at JNWR.ServerApplication.<clinit>(ServerApplication.java:18)
```

here is my persistence file

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_2.xsd"
             version="2.2">

    <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <description>
            Persistence unit for the JNWR Database
        </description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>JNWR.Entity.Customer</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver"
                      value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                      value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jwrms_db" />

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user"
                      value="defaultUser"/>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password"
                      value="defaultPassword%"/>

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                        value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect" />
                        
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql"
                      value="true" />

        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Already tried:

- Adding `META-INF` to classpath manually,
- moved it into the root folder,
- moved it into resources folder,
- moved persistence.xml to root, resources and of course `META-INF`.
- Imported the project into vscode (which worked but I want it to work in IntelliJ)

Comment: Please share the `pom.xml` file you're using for this setup.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in a `struts2` project created using `maven` archtype I put the persistence inside `webapp->WEB-INF` but it doesn't work. I fixed that issue just by going to `main->resources` i created a folder named `META-INF` inside the resources and it works fine :)

[image]